# Почему вводное слово не обособлено?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вставная-конструкция, вводное-слово

Есть тут [в справочнике Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123) одно такое предложеньице:

*Мне показалось даже, а может быть оно и в самом деле было так, что все стали к нам ласковее*. Вставка с запятыми.

По сути, должно быть либо так:

*Мне показалось даже, а может быть, оно и в самом деле было так, что все стали к нам ласковее (присоединительный союз примыкает к вводному слову)*, либо так:

*Мне показалось даже, а, может быть, оно и в самом деле было так, что все стали к нам ласковее* — вводное слово можно переставлять, поэтому с двух сторон.

Почему у Розенталя не обособлено?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я, как мэтр, считаю, что вводное это не обособлено-таки потому, что здесь оно начинает как бы вставную конструкцию, присоединённую посредством запятых (что, как там же и Розенталь-то пишет, нечастное явление). Так как союз *а* здесь — после него перед вводным нет запятых, как правило; это, однако, тоже от контекста зависит, — вводное слово как бы начинает это вставную конструкцию, а следовательно, его не надо обособлять. Примеры ещё:

> Я на улице один раз, а может не один раз, повстречал котёнка чёрно-пятностого.

> Я на улице один раз — а может, не один раз — повстречал котёнка чёрно-пятностого.

> Я на улице один раз (а может, не один раз) повстречал котёнка чёрно-пятностого.

Мне, однако, сэр, кажется, что, есль в конце так происходит, запятая всё же нужна, например как в *Она имеет кошку, а может быть, и две* или как в *Возможно, да, а может, и нет*.